# What password to give here?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql5

Before asking my question, i want to tell you background of my problem. I installed MYSQL workbench 8.0. When i first installed it then it was working fine but then I installed xamp, when i started sql in **xamp it shows an error i.e. most probably the error related to the port**. My friend suggested me to **delete the all the other SQL applications**, so I opened up control panel go to the uninstall software and install all the files starting or containing the word MYSQL. Then xamp started working but after a few days my university instructor tell me you can install M**YSQL workbench and xamp simultaneously** but what you have to do is change the port in xamp then it will be fine. After that i change the port number of MYSQL in xamp and test it i.e. is it working fine. It was working fine then I started installing MYSQL Workbench 8.0. It is stuck at this point, shown in the following figure

[image: This image shows where I am stuck]

It is asking for Password, i have forgotten what password i gave previous.
I shall be very thankful to you if someone help in proceeding from this step.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking how to **reset** your forgotten password? Certainly you're not serious about asking what the password is that you need to enter.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm. Linux guy here, but MySQL Workbench is a stand alone application, it shouldn't need to install a copy of MySQL server.  And XAMP should come with its own installer for MySQL server

For Workbench, you'll need to have hostnames and port, usernames, passwords, etc to set up connection profiles, but otherwise no password should be needed.

The short part of the direct answer to "which password is it" - the installer is seeing the other install of MySQL, and it wants to know the root user password for that install.